# Psycopg Not Showing Expected Data

Tags: python, psycopg2, psycopg

When I follow the [basic Psycopg example](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html), I expect to retrieve data from psql.

```
>>> import psycopg2

# Connect to an existing database
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")

# Open a cursor to perform database operations
>>> cur = conn.cursor()

# Execute a command: this creates a new table
>>> cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id serial PRIMARY KEY, num integer, data varchar);")

# Pass data to fill a query placeholders and let Psycopg perform
# the correct conversion (no more SQL injections!)
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)",
...      (100, "abc'def"))

# Query the database and obtain data as Python objects
>>> cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test;")
>>> cur.fetchone()
(1, 100, "abc'def")

# Make the changes to the database persistent
>>> conn.commit()

# Close communication with the database
>>> cur.close()
>>> conn.close()
```

Instead, I see the following:

```
>>> psql

>>> SELECT * FROM test;

(0 rows)
```

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by typing the following:

```
$ createdb test

$ psql -d test

>>> SELECT * FROM test;
```